# zip folder in bash

Tags: bash, zip

I have the files and folder like the below:

```
/myproject/config/1.xml
/myproject/src/1.py
```

I now zip the file like this using bash script:

```
cd myproject
zip -9 -r -q myfile.zip ./src/*
zip -9 -q myfile.zip ./config/1.xml
```

The zip file has 2 folders now, 1 config and 1.xml in it and 1 src and 1.py in it. This is what I want, the 2 folders are at the same level in the zip file.

Now I have to move the config folder out a level, src folder remains.

```
/config/1.xml
/myproject/src/1.py
```

I can change the codes to the below:

```
cd myproject
zip -9 -r -q myfile.zip ./src/*
zip -9 -q myfile.zip ../config/1.xml
```

But the folder config is no longer in the same level as the src.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to build a desired hierarchy inside the zipped archive you must pass to zip relative paths representing such a hierarchy. In your case `./src` and `../config` appear as different levels and this is reflected in the resulting archive. In order to make `config` and `src` appear on the same level, you must add an extra `cd` to your script:

```
cd /myproject
zip -9 -r -q /myfile.zip ./src/*
cd /
zip -9 -q /myfile.zip ./config/1.xml
```